# Posting json body via fetch from React CRUD app to ASP.Net controller. When posts hit the action they have null content

Tags: reactjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, fetch

I'm making a CRUD app as a learning exercise in React which interacts with an ASP API in the background. I'm using fetch to make the API calls. The [GetAll] and [GetById] calls all work fine but I can't get my [Posts] to work. I am able to post Json data from body via Postman and the Action on the API will receive it just fine but when I try and fire the same data across from the React project it doesn't work.

The action on the controller looks like this;

```
[Route("colours/new")]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult AddColour([FromBody]ColourModel colour)
        {
            colour.DateAdded = DateTime.Now; 

            _storageRepository.AddNewColour(colour);

            return Content("Your colour has been added");
        }
```

I am inspecting the process in the React Dev Tools in my browser and I can see that when I stringify my Json the values are populated. When it hits the breakpoint on the API controller, however, the object is null. As I mentioned previously; The action received the date from Postman without issue and I am targeting the correct action from my React app because it is hitting my breakpoint.

```
import { handleResponse, handleError } from "./apiUtils";
const baseUrl = process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + "/colours/";

export function saveColour(colour) {
  const data = JSON.stringify(colour);
  return fetch(baseUrl + "new", {
    method: "POST", 
    headers: { "content-type": "application/json" },
    body: data,
  })
    .then(handleResponse)
    .catch(handleError);
}
```

and handleResponse + handleError look like this;

```
export async function handleResponse(response) {
  if (response.ok) return response.json();
  if (response.status === 400) {
    const error = await response.text();
    throw new Error(error);
  }
  throw new Error("Network response was not ok.");
}

export function handleError(error) {
  console.error("API call failed. " + error);
  throw error;
}
```

Can anyone see where I might be going wrong with this? Why does my Json object arrive at the API as a null?

Comment: Are you sure the JSON you sent from Postman and the data you sent from React (JSON.stringify(data)) are exactly the same?

Comment: @SonNguyen Aaah - maybe not. If I copy the stringified json and post that from Postman that also arrives as null. Is there something I can do to my API action to encourage it to receive the json string or should I look at maybe sending the response as FormData and have the Api receive [FromForm] instead?

Comment: @SonNguyen The properties are sending as camelCase, yes. While checking to confirm that they were camelCased in the jsonString I noticed that a couple of properties were being sent as String when the ColourModel in the API was expecting Int. I have parsed the properties to Int in the react app and everything is working again.
Thankyou for pointing me in the right direction :)

Comment: I also suspected that you passed invalid model but I wondered why you passed model binding validation which should result in 400 error, not a null. So I deleted my comment and tried to point that out but you have already solved it. Glad to help